# SAS/PROC SQL: Eliminar ceros iniciales de un campo de tipo alfanumérico

Tags: sas

Necesito eliminar los ceros iniciales de un campo (figura como alfanumérico en la BD) tal que así:

```
ACOMETIDA
000000000003372501
000000000003407101
000000000003372401
000000000000000197
000000000500007733
000000000000000148
000000000100312222
000000000002187601
000000000002287801
000000000000000652
```

Es decir, es un número variable de caracteres pero siempre son ceros y están al principio de la cadena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede conseguir usando la función [VERIFY](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/fedsqlref/n1seyho5bsm4tpn1iqdzu4gqzfju.htm):

> VERIFY(target-expression, search–expression)
>
> The VERIFY function returns the position of the first character in
> target-expression that is not present in search-expression.

Así, dentro de una sentencia `SELECT`:

```
substr(sge.ACOMETIDA, verify(sge.ACOMETIDA, '0')) AS cod_acometida
```

Se tendría:

```
cod_acometida
3372501
3407101
3372401
197
500007733
148
100312222
2187601
2287801
652
```